# Retrieving single value from datatable how to check NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, null

I am trying to compare the value of a row `esmcost` with `psmcost` of table `wsmtbl` but `esmcost` cost value is `null` due to which I am getting the following error:

> Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'DBNull'

Is there any way to change the null value to zero?

This is the C# code

```
ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"] <> ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["psmcost"]
```

Comment: What is "<>"? What are you trying to do in this line of code, do you mean "!="?

Comment: yes @IrishChieftain

Comment: What types are ermcost and psmcost in the DB?

Comment: money with nullable

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
Decimal esmcost;
if (ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"] == DBNull.Value)
    esmcost = 0.00;
else
    esmcost = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"]);

Decimal psmcost;
if (ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["psmcost"] == DBNull.Value)
    psmcost = 0.00;
else
    psmcost = Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["psmcost"]);

if (esmcost != psmcost)
{
    ...
}
```

One could use the ternary operator syntax but I chose the above for readability reasons. For example:

```
Decimal esmcost = ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"]
    == DBNull.Value ? 0.00 : Convert.ToDecimal(ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"] == DBNull.Value)
{
   ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"] = 0;
}

 ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["esmcost"] != ds.Tables["wsmtbl"].Rows[0]["psmcost"];
```

Comment: You assume 0 and NULL are the same thing... if that were the case, surely the column would have been NOT NULL anyway and we would never have come to this...